# Wrap_content starting a new line

Tags: android, textview

I don't really know what should I search for so that is why I decided to ask here. I have a TextView which I want it to wrap by my content but not to exceed the application width, instead to start a new line and push the View below it one line beneath.

I believe it's a simple answer and I will be glad if someone will provide it to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Please do set the **width** as `wrap_content` and **height** also as `wrap_content`.

**2.** Keep `margin and padding` **to maintain the distance between other views, in you want the data to be in new line and Not using max line = 1**

**3.** If you **dont want to to create a new line**, then use the attribute `max line = 1`, this will keep adding to the TextView all **in one line**.

Answer (score 2):

set width as match_parent and height as wrap_content.

Comment: And how about not to collide with the other Views?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

Comment: Good, but not entirely solving my problem.